# Animatable Re-render animation React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, animation, react-native

I have an action bar with icons functioning as buttons as per this gif:
[image]

The animation works when the app loads, but when I click a button, and new buttons are loaded into the action bar, they are not animated as well, except for the last button.

I have tried the following:
- In my constructor:

```
this.state = {
  startAnimation: true,
};
```

and

```
componentDidUpdate() {
if (this.state.startAnimation) {
  this.refs.animatable.pulse();
}
}
```

and on my animatable view (each button is rendered with one)
    ref='animatable'

```
  onAnimationEnd={({ finished }) => {
    if (finished) {
      this.setState({ startAnimation: true });
    }
  }}
```

This does not work, Can anyone assist?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed my problem after a few days of messing around, I'm not sure if the code could be improved but if it helps anyone:

https://gist.github.com/IronCoderXYZ/9711463baa785c3786b6682234ed6c39